# C# WinForm 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am a beginner in C#.
I need professional help.
First of all, I have dynamic array code like C# WindowsForm code. This program is written in code without using Form.

The operating principle of the program is to go from the (0,0) point to the (9,9) point using the up, down, left and right arrow keys in the current code state.

Question 1. I want to make a red border on the button whenever I move the coordinates up, down, left, or right using the arrow keys, but I don't know how.

Question 2. For example, at point (0,0), I want to make it move only to the right and bottom. Likewise, at the (2,0) point, it should be set so that it cannot go only upward.

Question 3. I would like to implement so that 20 bombs are randomly sprinkled in the middle and if the bomb is treaded, an appropriate message is displayed and initialized to (0,0) points.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMylZ.png)

```
    namespace StartAndEnd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[,] arryButton;

        private bool[,] locationMe;

        private Point[,] arryLocation;
        private Size[,] arrySize;

        private Size FormSize;

        private int iWidthGab = 1;
        private int iHeightGab = 1;

        private int iCtrlwidth = 50;
        private int iCtrlHeight = 50;

        private int iX = 10;
        private int iY = 10;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetInit();
            SetEvent();
        }
        private void SetInit()
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;

            arryButton = new Button[iX, iY];
            arryLocation = new Point[iX, iY];
            arrySize = new Size[iX, iY];
            locationMe = new bool[iX, iY];

            for (int y = 0; y < iY; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < iX; x++)
                {
                    Button btn = new Button();

                    btn.Text = (x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString());
                    btn.Name = (x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString());

                    btn.BackColor = Color.Gray;

                    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    btn.Width = iCtrlwidth;
                    btn.Height = iCtrlHeight;

                    if (x > 0)
                    {
                        Button pbtn = arryButton[x - 1, y];
                        btn.Left = pbtn.Left + pbtn.Width + iWidthGab;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btn.Left = iWidthGab;
                    }
                    if (y > 0)
                    {
                        Button pbtn = arryButton[x, y - 1];
                        btn.Top = pbtn.Top + pbtn.Height + iHeightGab;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btn.Top = iHeightGab;
                    }

                    btn.MouseDown += Btn_MouseDown;
                    btn.MouseUp += Btn_MouseUp;

                    this.Controls.Add(btn);

                    arrySize[x, y] = btn.Size;
                    arryLocation[x, y] = btn.Location;
                    arryButton[x, y] = btn;

                    locationMe[x, y] = false;
                }
            }

            Button LastButton = arryButton[iX - 1, iY - 1];
            FormSize = new Size(LastButton.Left + LastButton.Width + iWidthGab, LastButton.Top + LastButton.Height + iHeightGab); // 만들어진 객체들을 포함하는 전쳋 창의 최소 크기 지정

            locationMe[0, 0] = true;
            this.ClientSize = FormSize;
        }

        private void Btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }

        private void Btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

        private void SetEvent()
        {
            this.Resize += Form1_Resize;
        }
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = false;

            if (this.ClientSize.Width < FormSize.Width)
                this.ClientSize = new Size(FormSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);

            if (this.ClientSize.Height < FormSize.Height)
                this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, FormSize.Height);

            int iRWidth = this.ClientSize.Width - FormSize.Width;
            int iRHeight = this.ClientSize.Height - FormSize.Height;

            for (int y = 0; y < iY; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < iX; x++)
                {
                    int iXGap = iRWidth / iX;
                    int iYGap = iRHeight / iY;

                    int iCtrlwidthMod = iCtrlwidth + iXGap;
                    int iCtrlheightMod = iCtrlHeight + iYGap;

                    this.Text = iRWidth + "," + iRHeight + "|" + iCtrlwidthMod + "," + iCtrlheightMod; ;

                    Button btn = arryButton[x, y];

                    if (x > 0)
                    {
                        Button pbtn = arryButton[x - 1, y];
                        btn.Left = pbtn.Left + iCtrlwidthMod + iWidthGab;
                        btn.Width = iCtrlwidthMod;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btn.Left = iWidthGab;
                        btn.Width = iCtrlwidthMod;
                    }
                    if (y > 0)
                    {
                        Button pbtn = arryButton[x, y - 1];
                        btn.Top = pbtn.Top + iCtrlheightMod + iHeightGab;
                        btn.Height = iCtrlheightMod;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btn.Top = iHeightGab;
                        btn.Height = iCtrlheightMod;
                    }

                }

            }
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Too many questions, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Welcome and good job on the detailed question with code example that's a good start, can you please improve your question and be more specific where are u stuck? whats not working, attach the errors if you have or specific scenarios that fails, that way we can help you faster and more productively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question, and edit your question so it is about one specific issue with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Comment: you have no keyboard handling in your code. Set KeyPreview property to true and handle KeyDown event.